# Why is this twurl command (run on linux, by golang exec) not being authenticated?

Tags: linux, go, exec, twurl

I'm currently working on a Golang website (running on Ubuntu) that will update a twitter status.  I used twurl customer key authentication on the system and I can successfully update the status if I type directly into the linux terminal.  For example

1. ssh/putty into target system
2. type in terminal: twurl -d 'status=is this thing on' /1.1/statuses/update.json
3. twitter status successfully updated

When I try to do the same through Golang exec, twitter gives me an authentication error.

```
func UpdateMainStatus(status string) {
    statusarg := `'` + "status=" + status + `'`
    out, err := exec.Command("twurl", "-d", statusarg, "/1.1/statuses/update.json").Output()
}
```

I've tried a couple of different methods for formatting the statusarg.  Printing the above statusarg to the console shows: 'status=Windows worked, Testing update on ubuntu.'

Twurl does seem to be run as out shows an error response from twitter,   {"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}.  I suspect it has to do with the setup of the command...???  Or maybe the interpretation of the single quotes in the status argument???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the single quotes:

```
statusarg := "status=" + status
```

In Golang, `"twurl"` is a string containing `twurl`. In particular, the string data does not include the double quotes. Those quotes are just Go syntax for strings.

In Bash, `'status=Foo'` is a string containing `status=Foo`. In particular, the string data does not include the single quotes. Those are just Bash syntax for uninterpolated strings.